# Facing difficulty with Hibernate HQL when applying it to H2

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, h2

I am new to hibernate and spring maven environment.

I have tried implementing an embedded db using H2, which earlier used MySQL. there are two DAO's

OffersDao.java

```
package com.skam940.main.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Component("offersDao")
@Transactional
public class OffersDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session session() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Offer> getOffers() {

        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(Offer.class);
        crit.createAlias("user", "u").add(Restrictions.eq("u.enabled", true));
        return crit.list();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Offer> getOffers(String username) {

        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(Offer.class);
        crit.createAlias("user", "u");

        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("u.enabled", true));
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("u.username", username));

        return crit.list();

    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(Offer offer) {

        session().saveOrUpdate(offer);

    }

    public boolean delete(int id) {

        Query query = session().createQuery("delete from Offer where id=:id");
        query.setLong("id", id);
        return query.executeUpdate() == 1;

    }

    public Offer getOffer(int id) {

        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(Offer.class);
        crit.createAlias("user", "u");

        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("u.enabled", true));
        crit.add(Restrictions.idEq(id));

        return (Offer) crit.uniqueResult();

    }

}
```

and UsersDao.java

```
package com.skam940.main.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
@Component("usersDao")
public class UsersDao {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session session() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void create(User user) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        session().save(user);

    }

    public boolean exists(String username) {
        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(User.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.idEq(username));

        User user = (User) crit.uniqueResult();
        return user != null;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return session().createQuery("from User").list();
    }

}
```

no the thing is I get an exception of

> HTTP Status 500 - PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username, password, enabled from users where binary username = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "BINARY" not found; SQL statement:

And the thing I want to do here to make the username case sensitive, and apparently H2 recognises BINARY as a table name but not as a type or what ever you call that, can any one tell which which method is implementing this SQL grammar?

User.java

```
 package com.skam940.main.dao;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import com.skam940.main.validation.ValidEmail;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @NotBlank(groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    @Size(min=6, max=15, groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\w{8,}$", groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\S+$", groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    @Size(min=8, max=15, groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    private String password;

    @ValidEmail(groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    @Size(min=3, max=30, groups={FormValidationGroup.class})
    private String name;

    private boolean enabled = false;
    private String authority;


    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String name, String password, String email, boolean enabled,
            String authority) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((authority == null) ? 0 : authority.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (enabled ? 1231 : 1237);
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (authority == null) {
            if (other.authority != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!authority.equals(other.authority))
            return false;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (enabled != other.enabled)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (username == null) {
            if (other.username != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [username=" + username + ", email=" + email + ", name="
                + name + ", enabled=" + enabled + ", authority=" + authority
                + "]";
    }




}
```

Offer.java

```
package com.skam940.main.dao;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="offers")
public class Offer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    // because this is an auto increment value
    private int id;

    @Size(min=5, max=255, groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    @Column(name="text")
    private String text;

    // every user can have only one offer
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="username")
    private User user;

    public Offer() {
        this.user = new User();
    }

    public Offer(User user, String text) {
        this.user = user;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Offer(int id, User user, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((text == null) ? 0 : text.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((user == null) ? 0 : user.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Offer other = (Offer) obj;
        if (text == null) {
            if (other.text != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!text.equals(other.text))
            return false;
        if (user == null) {
            if (other.user != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!user.equals(other.user))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Offer [id=" + id + ", text=" + text + ", user=" + user + "]";
    }





}
```

the full file content is available here -> https://app.box.com/s/c3uq71khbwf05p8asu27

Comment: Doesn't `Restrictions.eq` work correctly instead of `Restrictions.idEq` in the exists method (which I am guessing is where the problem is)?

Comment: @geoand i tried that, I thing it was implemented because username is a foreign key and primary key integration.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a foreign key or not, all you are doing is using it as a criterion

Comment: can you post your UDT mapping?

Comment: @geoand I have tried changing that and i get an error `the method eq(String, Object0 is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I have no idea what that is.

Comment: your user and offer mappings

Comment: How do you map boolean property "enabled" in users table? Did you define <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</property>?

Comment: @MagicWand I have no idea i got this as a tutorial online... but i have attached the complete file of it here -> [link](https://app.box.com/s/c3uq71khbwf05p8asu27)

Comment: Please check in dabatase in table USERS what column type is mapped to boolean property "enabled". And if it is e.g. varchar type, what values are written to it. If it is true and false, you need to add the property mentioned in my last comment so that Hibernate is able to map string true to boolean.

Comment: @magicwand ya it is a tinyit[1] with a default value 1 but it does not say as a Boolean.. Do you want me to change it? Does h2 support boolean type? And where should I write that property tag? Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is coming from your Spring security configuration, please check security-context.xml, you can find Spring security authentication provider that uses authorities-by-username-query as

```
select username, authority from users where binary username = ?
```

This query uses MySQL-specific function BINARY for case-sensitive comparison (http://gilfster.blogspot.com/2005/08/case-sensitivity-in-mysql.html). H2, on the other hand, is case sensitive by default.

Try to change it with

```
select username, authority from users where username = ?
```

The same applies to users-by-username-query property.